# How to get date range in EXCEL to ListView?

Tags: excel, vba, office-interop

I already have a code for getting the data from EXCEL to ListView But i only want a specific date range.

This is what I have tried. but it's not Working.

```
Dim cCount As Integer
Dim azr As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
azr = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

Dim a As String
Dim b As String
a = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")
b = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")

Dim ex As String
ex = azr.Cells(cCount, 2).value.ToString

If ((ex >= a) And b >= ex) Then
    For cCount = 2 To azr.Rows.Count
        Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()

        newitem.Text = azr.Cells(cCount, 1).value.ToString
        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 2).value.ToString)
        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 3).value.ToString)
        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 4).value.ToString)
        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 5).value.ToString)

        LvRawExcel.Items.Add(newitem)

        count = count + 1
        LblCount.Text = count
    Next
End If
```

It just give me this error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Is there any other way to get the date range?

[Sample Picture of EXCEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHIUJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just added this code :

```
Dim cCount As Integer
Dim azr As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
azr = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

For cCount = 2 To azr.Rows.Count

    Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()
    Dim str As String = (azr.Cells(cCount, 2).value.ToString)               'added this

    Dim dFromDate As Date
    dFromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") 'added this

    Dim dToDate As Date                                                     'added this
    dToDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")               'added this

    If ((str >= dFromDate) And (str <= dToDate)) Then 'Make this condition
        newitem.Text = azr.Cells(cCount, 1).value.ToString

        newitem.SubItems.Add(Format(azr.Cells(cCount, 2).value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:00"))

        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 3).value.ToString)
        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 4).value.ToString)
        newitem.SubItems.Add(azr.Cells(cCount, 5).value.ToString)

        LvRawExcel.Items.Add(newitem)

        count = count + 1
        LblCount.Text = count
    Else

    End If

Next
```